# Heroku rejects push from Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Right after running 'heroku run rake db:migrate', the error includes:

```
    remote:        Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 77 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

    remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object

remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to postil9.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/postil9.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/postil9.git
```

And here's my 'production.rb' file:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_files = ENV["RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES"].present?
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "postil9.herokuapp.com"}
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket: ENV.fetch("S3_BUCKET_NAME"),
    access_key_id: ENV.fetch("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
    secret_access_key: ENV.fetch("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
    s3_region: ENV.fetch("AWS_REGION"),
  }
}

  Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"

end
```

My application.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Workspace
  class Application < Rails::Application


    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

Already tried bundle install --without production, but still have no clue about the solution.
The app works perfectly on the Rails server.

Comment: Can you give more information about of issue?

Comment: More from the output would be useful, there is typically an error pointed out around the top, just put the whole trace in here if you could and it should help.

Comment: Apparently it's a syntax error, some uncompleted quote
It would be good if you put the error's output, complete to see in which file the problem is

Comment: Trying to, but the site keeps asking me to add more details instead of code. There's no much more details I can add to balance with the amount of code.

Comment: "The app works perfectly on the Rails server." - if by "rails server" you mean development mode and this is indeed so, then the problem must be in `config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: the trace of the error is not complete and it is necessary to determine in what file is the quote without closing, check your code in search of a string that is not enclosed in quotes

Comment: This part loks interesting: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'config' for main:Object` have a look in `config/environments/production.rb` and see if you've accidentally got a gap between the word `config` and the method you're calling on it somewhere...

Comment: Ok, so I just posted my production.rb file on here. I can't really find an error there in regards to punctiation or quotes. Maybe something else then?

Comment: Check whether you have `config` defined in `application.rb`. Something like `def config #:nodoc:
      @config ||= Application::Configuration.new(self.class.find_root(self.class.called_from))
    end `

Comment: I don't have it on my application.rb file, but just in case I've posted it if you want to take it a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application.rb file you have :

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

And it's outside the application class and that's why it raising :

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object
```

because 'config' doesn't exists outside the app class, your application.rb should look like this :

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Workspace
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false # Moved in app class
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! It solved this problem BUT now it's pointing another one from my 'production.rb' file:  rake aborted!
remote:        KeyError: key not found: "S3_BUCKET_NAME"

Comment: there is this line ENV.fetch("S3_BUCKET_NAME") in your config files, which raise an error if env variable is missing, you have to set S3_BUCKET_NAME in your env

Comment: I see. I'll take care of it from now on. Thanks a lot, everyone!